# Android Camera preview not working properly on bigger screen devices

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, camera-calibration

Camera preview in my app is not working properly on bigger screen devices such as Nexus 4/5 it works fine on smaller screen devices such as Nexus S . I used the width & height parameter in my app they are basically screen size. If I set those parameter manually the app works fine but if I dynamically calculate the size and use it in the app, the camera preview doesn't work properly see below image for details:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOiFQ.png "screenshot of app nexus 5"

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerImg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        >



            <SurfaceView
                android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/kitten_2"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />
```

To calculate the screen size I'm using the below code. I checked the code is working properly on bigger screen devices the values are accurate

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    height  = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    width  = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

To set relate layout size:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new             
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height); 
mImageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
mImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
```

To set camera preview size:

```
if (previewing) {
            camera.stopPreview();
            previewing = false;
        }
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            parameters.setPreviewSize(width,height);
            parameters.setPictureSize(width,height);
```

Any help appreciated.

P.S Sorry about English  it is my second language.